# Apple watch clear images caching

Tags: ios, caching, watchkit, apple-watch, clear-cache

I have a watch app, and I'm receiving images through `WKInterfaceController openParentApplication` at every 0.1 second and I'm making an animation, everything is working fine, but after 30 seconds the app slows down, I think the problem is that there are a lot of images, how to clear cache???? Or is there a method that release old images, and after I re-run app everything is working fine. Thanks!